# Python number getting rounded in csv file

Tags: python

I am gathering tweet data and writing it to a csv file. Everything works perfect when I print status ID #'s in IDLE:

```
with open('C:/location/filename.csv', 'wb') as acsv:
    w = csv.writer(acsv)
    w.writerow(('ID'))
    for statusObj in results:
        statid = statusObj.id
    w.writerow((statid))
```

This prints a status ID as expected (e.g. 238669617898323968). But when I open the csv file to check it, the last 3 digits are rounded to 238669617898323000. What is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: "This prints a status ID as expected" … are you sure? There are no `print` statement in your code. I'm suspicious of `results`.

Comment: @supervacuo yes, this is an edited version of the full code. I pasted the status ID directly from IDLE

Comment: Are you opening the file in Excel? Excel has a habit of rounding numbers. Open it in a text editor to be sure.

Comment: @nneonneo Dammit, I officially feel incredibly stupid now. The value is not rounded in a text editor. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to force excel not to round these values so I can use it for data analysis?

Comment: Set the cell format to text in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is...don't trust Excel to display your data exactly as entered.

Comment: I have to admit -- That was some pretty fantastic introspection you did on this question ... (+1)

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://appscout.pcmag.com/your-questions/274348-handle-huge-integers-in-excel) for the reason why, but it boils down to Excel only handling 15-16 digit numbers. I'm making an assumption here, but if you're pulling tweets, I'm assuming you're using the Twitter API? If so, there is an `id_str` field that will return the ID as a string, and you could then store it in your CSV and handle converting it at other point in your program (see [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-ids-json-and-snowflake) for more information).

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of this limitation in Excel, and I see it is standard in others like open office as well which explains why that didn't work either.